# Why do we say LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

As a new programmer who is learning how to use LINQ, I'm confused as to why the word query is often appended to LINQ (for example, "this LINQ query").

Isn't this attachment superfluous, considering that LINQ is an abbreviation for Language Integrated Query? Do forgive me if this turns out to be a silly question as I couldn't find much research on this.

**Edit:**

It did turn out to be a silly question but I learnt that LINQ is an abbreviation for a set of technologies and that a LINQ query is just a query expressed via said technologies. Either that or it can be attributed to the RAS Syndrome that Michael spoke of.

Comment: You can add LINQ query to this list: DC Comics, ATM Machine, LCD display

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Do ensure that you don't just accept whatever PIN number the bank gives you. You should ask for a Personal PIN Number.

Comment: "Query" is not appended to "LINQ." "LINQ" is prepended to "query." A LINQ query is a type of query.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the world LINQ refers to a component in .NET framework. the LINQ query is a syntax that is written on basis of this component,It's like SQL and SQL query.

Comment: LINQ isn't a component in .NET. LINQ stands for "Language INtegrated Query". LINQ is the query.

Comment: @Enigmativity apparently you know better than Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query

Comment: I agree with this answer.LINQ is not just an abbreviation.

Comment: @Enigmativity LINQ is not the query. It is a component, actually.

Comment: Even though I realize its a component, I was curious as to how "LINQ query" came about in colloquial use. @MichaelBuen found a reason as to why that may be but I'm wondering if any other experts here might have another reason.

Comment: @ehsankiani - No, I'm going to stick with my original assessment. Wikipedia has it wrong with the use of the word [component](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/component).

Comment: @preciousbetine - Please show me **the** component that is LINQ.